# concatenate array field in one record with all other recodes - pySpark

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Schema

```
 root
     |-- userId: string (nullable = true)
     |-- languageknowList: array (nullable = true)
     |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
     |    |    |-- code: string (nullable = false)
     |    |    |-- description: string (nullable = false)
     |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = false)
```

In this schema there is a user with userId 0, I have to concatenate the languageknowList in userId 0 with  languageknowList of all other users.

How can I do that

Example:
input data to DF

```
[{
  "userId":1,
  "languageknowList": [[10,"Hindi","Hindi"],[11,"Spanish","Spanish"]]
},
{
  "userId":2,
  "languageknowList": [[11,"Spanish","Spanish"]]
},
{
  "userId":0,
  "languageknowList": [[1,"English","English"],[2,"German","German"]]
}]
```

output df should be like:

```
[{
  "userId":1,
  "languageknowList": [[10,"Hindi","Hindi"],[11,"Spanish","Spanish"],[1,"English","English"],[2,"German","German"]]
},
{
  "userId":2,
  "languageknowList": [[11,"Spanish","Spanish"],[1,"English","English"],[2,"German","German"]]
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cross join the dataframe to the row with `userId = 0`, and `concat` the arrays of languages:

```
result = df.filter('userId != 0').crossJoin(
    df.filter('userId = 0').select('languageknowList').toDF('language')
).select(
    'userId',
    F.concat('languageknowList', 'language').alias('languageknowList')
)

result.show(20,0)
+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|userId|languageknowList                                                                        |
+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1     |[[10, Hindi, Hindi], [11, Spanish, Spanish], [1, English, English], [2, German, German]]|
|2     |[[11, Spanish, Spanish], [1, English, English], [2, German, German]]                    |
+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

result.coalesce(1).write.json('result')
```

```
$ cat result/part-00000-b34b3748-71b5-46d4-b011-6b208978cc5a-c000.json
{"userId":1,"languageknowList":[["10","Hindi","Hindi"],["11","Spanish","Spanish"],["1","English","English"],["2","German","German"]]}
{"userId":2,"languageknowList":[["11","Spanish","Spanish"],["1","English","English"],["2","German","German"]]}
```

Comment: facing error:-  Detected implicit cartesian product for INNER join between logical plans

Comment: instead of join I have used crossJoin. Now it is working fine.

Comment: what is coalesce(1)

Comment: It's for collecting the whole dataframe into a single partition so that the output will not be split into multiple json files. It should only be used if the dataframe is small, otherwise it may cause out of memory problems.